# What are the different ways to access the hash variables in perl

Tags: perl

According to my basic understanding we can access the values of an hash as follows:

```
$hash_name{key1}{key2};       #In case of an nested hash 
$hash_reference->{key1}{key2} #if we have the reference to the hash instead of the hash we can access as
```

But in in one the archived code I have seen as follows:

```
$sc1 = %par->{'a'}{'b'};
@a1 = %par->{'a'}{'c'};
%c3 = %par->{'a'}{'d'};
```

What does it actually mean? Can some one help me on this?

Comment: It means an error. Throw it away.

Answer (score 4):

All three variants you posted will produce a syntax error while under `use strict`, and an additional warning with `use warnings` on Perls older than Perl 5.22. The output I show here is from Perl 5.20.1.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $par = { a => { b => 1, c => 2, d => 3 } };

my $sc1 = %par->{'a'}{'b'};
my @a1 = %par->{'a'}{'c'};
my %c3 = %par->{'a'}{'d'};

__END__
Using a hash as a reference is deprecated at /home/foo/code/scratch.pl line 700.
Using a hash as a reference is deprecated at /home/foo/code/scratch.pl line 701.
Using a hash as a reference is deprecated at /home/foo/code/scratch.pl line 702.
Global symbol "%par" requires explicit package name at /home/foo/code/scratch.pl line 700.
Global symbol "%par" requires explicit package name at /home/foo/code/scratch.pl line 701.
Global symbol "%par" requires explicit package name at /home/foo/code/scratch.pl line 702.
Execution of /home/foo/code/scratch.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Without `strict` and `warnings`, it will compile, but produce nonsense.

```
no strict;
no warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my $par = { a => { b => 1, c => 2, d => 3 } };

my $sc1 = %par->{'a'}{'b'};
my @a1 = %par->{'a'}{'c'};
my %c3 = %par->{'a'}{'d'};

p $sc1;
p @a1;
p %c3;

__END__

undef
[
    [0] undef
]
{
    ''   undef
}
```

That said, always `use strict` and `use warnings` for your Perl programs, and listen to the warnings it shows you.

Comment: The expression `%par->{'a'}{'b'}` is compiled as `\(%par)->{'a'}{'b'}` in all versions of perl before 5.22, so the existence of the hash reference `$par` is irrelevant. If instead you declared `my %par = ( a => { b => 1, c => 2, d => 3 } )` and tested on Perl v5.20 or earlier then `Data::Dump` would at least show something useful, even though the syntax is certainly wrong and has been deprecated for a long time

Comment: @Borodin I see. I'll add my Perl version to the answer.

Comment: @Borodin so what ever the code($sc1 = %par->{'a'}{'b'};) that i have posted in the above question make sense?

Answer (score 2):

This originates as an issue with earlier perl releases whereby an expression like

```
%par->{'a'}
```

would be silently interpreted as

```
(\%par)->{'a'}
```

I'm unclear whether this was a bug, or if it was intended behaviour. Either way it has been declared undesirable, and was first documented to be deprecated, then changed to cause deprecation warnings, and finally in Perl v5.22 it causes a fatal error so your code won't even compile any longer

> Can't use a hash as a reference

Either of these should properly be written as just

```
$par{'a'}
```

The [perldelta document for version 22 of Perl 5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldelta.html#Using-a-hash-or-an-array-as-a-reference-are-now-fatal-errors) has this

> **Using a hash or an array as a reference are now fatal errors**
>
> For example, `%foo->{"bar"}` now causes a fatal compilation error. These have been deprecated since before v5.8, and have raised deprecation warnings since then.

In general, the three lines that you quote should be fixed by replacing `%par->` with `$par`

```
$sc1 = $par{'a'}{'b'};
@a1  = $par{'a'}{'c'};
%c3  = $par{'a'}{'d'};
```

However the second will set `@a1` to have a single element and could perhaps better be written as `@a1 = ( $par{'a'}{'c'} )` to emphasise that it is a list assignment, and the third is assigning a single scalar to a hash, which will cause the warning

> Odd number of elements in hash assignment

so the semantic is wrong as well as the syntax